# Query with a sequence of "and not like"

Tags: ms-access, fields

I have a table called `VHS_Metadata_Aug52014` with columns:

```
Title, Description,Tag, Speaker, VIP, FilmingLocation, Notes
```

I'm trying to write a query that returns all records for which the word `"News"` is not in any value. There are indeed records of this type. However, the query below returns nothing. So, I'm guessing I'm not quite understanding how to do it. I'm using MS Access, where the wildcard is `*`.

UPDATE: I just tried also using the syntax:

```
Not VHS_Metadata_Aug52014!Description like '*News*'
```

And I'm still getting no hits.

```
select * from VHS_Metadata_Aug52014 where (
VHS_Metadata_Aug52014!Title Not like '*' & 'News' & '*'
And
VHS_Metadata_Aug52014!Description Not like '*' & 'News' & '*'
And
VHS_Metadata_Aug52014!Tag Not like '*' & 'News' & '*'
And
VHS_Metadata_Aug52014!Speaker Not like '*' & 'News' & '*'
And  
VHS_Metadata_Aug52014!VIP Not like '*' & 'News' & '*'
And
VHS_Metadata_Aug52014!FilmingLocation Not like '*' & 'News' & '*'
And
VHS_Metadata_Aug52014!Notes Not like '*' & 'News' & '*'
) ;
```

Comment: Added an `ms-access` tag.

Comment: The query seems correct. Are you sure there are rows that match these conditions? And why `Not like '*' & 'News' & '*'` instead of `Not like '*News*'` ?

Comment: Since you originally tagged only `sql` not `ms-access` are you using an MS Access client to access a SQL Server database?

Comment: @RLF Would SQL-Server accept the `!` between table and column name?

Comment: I would think not, so my question was probably pointless.

Comment: @RLF I'm using Access to access (!) a local Access database.

Comment: @ypercube Not sure. I think that's the first solution I found on the internet ;)  Yours seems a lot simpler!

Comment: @ypercube Oh, and yes, I'm 100% certain there are quite a few rows in the table where NONE of the fields have the word "News". Really.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is most likely some `NULL` values. Unfortunately, `NULL LIKE 'anypattern'` will not result in `FALSE` but in `UNKNOWN` and `NOT UNKNOWN` is still `UNKNOWN`. So any row where one or more of the values is Null, will not be in the result list because `WHERE` filters all rows that the condition is anything but `TRUE` (`FALSE` and `UKNOWN` get rejected).

Try this change:

```
select * from VHS_Metadata_Aug52014 where 
(Title Not like '*' & 'News' & '*'           Or Title Is Null)
And
(Description Not like '*' & 'News' & '*'     Or Description Is Null)
And
(Tag Not like '*' & 'News' & '*'             Or Tag Is Null)
And
(Speaker Not like '*' & 'News' & '*'         Or Speaker Is Null)
And  
(VIP Not like '*' & 'News' & '*'             Or VIP Is Null)
And
(FilmingLocation Not like '*' & 'News' & '*' Or FilmingLocation Is Null)
And
(Notes Not like '*' & 'News' & '*'           Or Notes Is Null)
;
```

Comment: That may be it. There are definitely fields that are blank (which I guess is null?). So, something that I didn't explain is that my query string is actually being programmatically generated from a search form. The string in question is when I do a keyword search for all fields (generated by a loop over the fields). In that case, should I always include the "Or Title Is Null"?

Comment: Well, I tried it, and still no hits. BTW, can I really eliminate the reference to the database name and just use the field name as you did?

Comment: Oops. I had "is not null".  Worked!

Answer (score 0):

For Microsoft SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc the wildcard is not * but is %.

If you search for "wildcards" in your SQL documentation you should find your particular server's supported wildcards.

EDIT: Post comment: Sorry, I have never written MS Access queries.

Comment: I'm using MS Access. The wildcard there seems to be "*".  Editing question to reflect this.